# Is it possible to convert angularjs web application to IOS app with Ibeacon search functionality?

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ibeacon

I have developed a web application using angularjs, now i want to convert ios application with iBeacons device searching functionality.

Is it possible to do this, any one please give me advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible, you can repurpose your Angular single page app into a Cordova/PhoneGap container, then use appropriate plugins (which bridge platform specific native code to Javascript) to add iBeacon or other beacon support.  If you don't find plugins that do what you want, you can create your own if you are comfortable working in the native languages of the platforms you want to use (Java for Android, Objective C or Swift for iOS).

Example plugins that already exist to help with this would be:

- [cordova-plugin-ibeacon](https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon)
- [ngCordova Cordova Beacon](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/beacon/)

There's an example of how to go about this using Angular JS / Ionic framework [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/09/support-ibeacons-in-your-ionic-framework-mobile-app/).

Comment: Hi @simon Thanks for your quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to directly scan for beacons in JavaScript.**  This is true whether you are talking about a web app running in Mobile Safari on iOS or inside a `UIWebView` container within a native iOS Web app.

If you want to combine JavaScript-based apps with beacons, **the alternative is to build Hybrid apps using technologies like Cordova or Ionic** (which is built off of Cordova).  You can then use Cordova plugins that let you interact with native code that does the beacon scanning, and pass it back to your JavaScript application.  One such plugin that accomplishes this is here:

https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon

There are limitations with this approach.  Beacon scanning typically has to be in the foreground, and you can't really wake up the app on beacon detection.

Full disclosure:  I am the lead developer on the [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/altbeacon/android-beacon-library) open source project upon which the above plugin is based.